# MySQL Procedural Languages?

Tags: mysql

What procedural languages are available for writing stored procedures or functions in MySQL?

Comment: Just what MySQL provides: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just MySQL. Quoting [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html):

> The LANGUAGE characteristic indicates
>   the language in which the routine is
>   written. The server ignores this
>   characteristic; only SQL routines are
>   supported.

Comment: What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures are created within mysql by a standard defintion.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html